# Angular Material placeholder is not working with @Input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular materuial. In the parent component I have

```
<app-multiselect 
    [optionsList]="propertyTypeList"
    [multiple]=true
    [placeholder]="Select"
    ></app-multiselect>
```

In the child component in the .ts file I am using an @Input

```
@Input() placeholder: string;
```

In the child html file I have

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select 
  [multiple]="multiple"
  [placeholder]="placeholder">
    <mat-option 
    *ngFor="let item of optionsList" 
    [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am getting "placeholder" instead of "Select".

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing String as a Input, it needs to be enclosed within **`''`**

```
<app-multiselect [placeholder]="'Select'" ></app-multiselect>
```

And when you are binding, you should use string interpolation as **`{{}}`**

```
 <mat-select placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-ucmfzw?file=app.component.html)**

Comment: It is working because you are not passing it throught @Input from another element. I mention to this: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api. If I pass it throught Input and use your script I am getting just a hardcoded ward "Select"

Comment: what do you mean? just check the demo above, it has a parent and child component

Comment: if you see there is a app.component and select component which users mat-select

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to use an @Input decorator and pass the "Select" from another element. In your example it is just a hardcoded constant. In angular material they mention an option to pass it through Input. Let's say I want to use the select with multiple instances and each time I want to pass different placeholder. It is what I mention

Comment: It's not. Where is your other element where you pass it from and the @Input decorator in the .ts file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182125/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-tuvia-khusid).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-ucmfzw?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.ts

Comment: It is working :) Thanks mate! So, the issue is to add ' ' in the parent component.

Comment: That's what I have been telling , please make sure to mark answer

Answer (score 0):

In the child HTML, instead of using quotes use double curly bracket:

`[placeholder]={{placeholder}}`

By using double quotes you are assigning the literal value of the string "placeholder", whereas Angular takes the value of the variable when it's between double curly brackets {{}}.

Comment: Tried both [placeholder]={{placeholder}} and [placeholder]="{{placeholder}}". It gives errors. [multiple]="multiple" is working and the placeholder should work in a same way. :(

Comment: Where are you passing the different placeholder from? if you want to change the @Input() placeholder value then you can create a method inside the component to change it

Comment: Thanks! The solution has been found! Please, look at the above chat

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me; I got this solution from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-ucmfzw?file=app.component.html

```
<app-multiselect 
    placeholder="{{'Select'}}"
    ></app-multiselect>
```